# A hyperbolic solution to this differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following differential equation: $$\Big(\frac{dy}{dx}\Big)^2=\frac{y^2-A^2}{A^2}.$$ I am looking to obtain a solution $$y(x)=A\cosh\Big({\frac{x+B}{A}}\Big),$$ where B and A are constants.

I have tried square-rooting and Taylor expanding, substitution of an integral but am getting nowhere.

Sorry if this is an inappropriate homework question but it has been annoying me for too long today...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$\dfrac{dy}{\sqrt{y^2-A^2}}=\pm\dfrac{dx}{A}$$

The only thing you need to do is to find the integral of the expression on the left side.

Comment: left hand side?

Answer (score 1):

The way to test whether something is a solution of a differential equation is to substitute it in to the differential equation and check that both sides simplify to the same thing.